# JSON Object should not add if it is repeated

Tags: java, arrays, json, for-loop

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
JSONArray finaljson = new JSONArray();
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    System.out.println("Enter Version Name");
    String vName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Version Key");
    ;
    String vKey = input.next();
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    if (!root.has("versionName")) {
        root.put("versionName", vName);
        root.put("versionKey", vKey);
    }

    JSONArray issue = new JSONArray();
    System.out.println("Enter Epic Name");
    String epicName = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter Epic Key");
    String epicKey = input.next();
    JSONObject epicData = new JSONObject();
    epicData.put("epickKey", epicKey);
    epicData.put("epickName", epicName);
    issue.put(epicData);

    root.put("issue", issue);
    finaljson.put(root);
}

System.out.println("JSON DATA" + finaljson.toString());
```

Hey Making a JSON,as from the code if user will enter versionname is multiple time that it should not add in root jsonobject. so how to restrict it.

```
[
    {
        "versionKey": "vkey1",
        "issue": [
            {
                "epickName": "e1",
                "epickKey": "ekey1"
            }
        ],
        "versionName": "v1"
    },
    {
        "versionKey": "vkey1",
        "issue": [
            {
                "epickName": "e2",
                "epickKey": "eky2"
            }
        ],
        "versionName": "v1"
    }
]
```

but want

```
[
    {
        "versionKey": "vkey1",
        "issue": [
            {
                "epickName": "e1",
                "epickKey": "eky1"
            },
            {
                "epickName": "e2",
                "epickKey": "eky2"
            }
        ],
        "versionName": "v1"
    }
]
```

can you help me how to make this type of dynamic json data

Comment: Please reformulate your question ?? Sorry don't understand what you need? or what is your problem?

Comment: From Above Code i can make JSON where it's define like first json,  i want to make json json like secound json i have given.
i am unable to add epicData json object secound time if version name is same.
@esprittn

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the output to be like the second JSON array in your question. Changing where you loop should do the trick:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
JSONArray finaljson = new JSONArray();

System.out.println("Enter Version Name");
String vName = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter Version Key");;
String vKey = input.next();
JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
if (!root.has("versionName")) {
    root.put("versionName", vName);
    root.put("versionKey", vKey);
}

JSONArray issue = new JSONArray();
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    System.out.println("Enter Epic Name");
    String epicName = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter Epic Key");
    String epicKey = input.next();
    JSONObject epicData = new JSONObject();
    epicData.put("epickKey", epicKey);
    epicData.put("epickName", epicName);
    issue.put(epicData);
}

root.put("issue", issue);
finaljson.put(root);

System.out.println("JSON DATA" + finaljson.toString());
```

I tested with the input you have. Here is the formatted JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "issue": [
            {
                "epickKey": "eky1",
                "epickName": "e1"
            },
            {
                "epickKey": "eky2",
                "epickName": "e2"
            }
        ],
        "versionName": "vkey1",
        "versionKey": "v1"
    }
]
```

Comment: i cant put for loop that i have already tried, i have to check that version name by each loop.

Comment: Can't we make another logic... i only want to put that if versionName is same don't put it in root object else it's fine to put.

Comment: Can you be more clear? If the version-name is the same as the version-key?

Comment: Ya it's same there.. but it's ok there if we match only one thing. and data is coming from data base. so it will not create a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I change your code and I add two other class. One named Data  for (versionKey, nameKey), the second one Epic for (epickName,epickKey)
and to generate Json, I use Gson lib.
 This code :

Epic Class:

```
public class Epic {

    private String epicName;
    private String epicKey;

    public Epic() {

    }

    public Epic(String epicName, String epicKey) {  
        this.epicName = epicName;
        this.epicKey = epicKey;
    }

    public String getEpicName() {
        return epicName;
    }
    public void setEpicName(String epicName) {
        this.epicName = epicName;
    }
    public String getEpicKey() {
        return epicKey;
    }
    public void setEpicKey(String epicKey) {
        this.epicKey = epicKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Epic [epicName=");
        builder.append(epicName);
        builder.append(", epicKey=");
        builder.append(epicKey);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Data Class :

```
import java.util.List;


public class Data {

    private String versionName;
    private String versionKey;
    private List<Epic> epics;

    public Data() {

    }

    public Data(String versionName, String versionKey, List<Epic> epics) {  
        this.versionName = versionName;
        this.versionKey = versionKey;
        this.epics = epics;
    }

    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }
    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }
    public String getVersionKey() {
        return versionKey;
    }
    public void setVersionKey(String versionKey) {
        this.versionKey = versionKey;
    }
    public List<Epic> getEpics() {
        return epics;
    }
    public void setEpics(List<Epic> epics) {
        this.epics = epics;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((versionKey == null) ? 0 : versionKey.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((versionName == null) ? 0 : versionName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Data other = (Data) obj;
        if (versionKey == null) {
            if (other.versionKey != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!versionKey.equals(other.versionKey))
            return false;
        if (versionName == null) {
            if (other.versionName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!versionName.equals(other.versionName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Data [versionName=");
        builder.append(versionName);
        builder.append(", versionKey=");
        builder.append(versionKey);
        builder.append(", epics=");
        builder.append(epics);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main {


    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
        boolean add = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            add = false;
            Data data = new Data();
            System.out.println("Enter Version Name");
            data.setVersionName(input.next());
            System.out.println("Enter Version Key");
            data.setVersionKey(input.next());

            Epic epic = new Epic();
            System.out.println("Enter Epic Name");
            epic.setEpicName(input.next());
            System.out.println("Enter Epic Key");
            epic.setEpicKey(input.next());

            List<Epic> epics = new ArrayList<Epic>();
            if(datas.isEmpty()){

                epics.add(epic);
                data.setEpics(epics);
                datas.add(data);
            }else{
                for(Data d:datas){
                    if(d.equals(data)){
                        d.getEpics().add(epic);
                        add=true;
                    }
                }
                if(!add){
                    epics.add(epic);
                    data.setEpics(epics);
                    datas.add(data);
                }
            }

        }
        //Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        //System.out.println(gson.toJson(datas));
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(datas);  
        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());



    }

}
```

PS: Url to download [Gson API](https://github.com/google/gson)

---

**Edit**

I made a change in the Main Class to use json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
Take a look at this URL:
[json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read in your json using Gson:

1. Define Pojos for your Json Objects:

   ```
   public class Epic {
       String versionKey, versionName;
       Issue issue;
   }

   public class Issue{
       String epicName, epicKey;
   }
   ```
2. Load Pojos from json using Gson

   ```
   // Create gson object
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

   // Load your json objects:
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.json"));  
   List<Epic> epics = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Epic>>() {}.getType());
   ```
3. Create the class structure you want for your "multi-issue-epics":

   ```
   // This will be used to store in the format you want
   public class MultiIssueEpic{
       public String versionKey, versionName;
       public Set<Issue> issueSet;

       public MultiIssueEpic(Epic epic){
           this.versionName = epic.versionName;
           this.versionKey = epic.versionKey;
           this.issueSet = new HashSet<>();
           this.issueSet.add(epic.issue);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Build the `MultiIssueEpic` up from your `List<Epic>`:

   ```
   Map<String, MultiIssueEpic> epicMap = new HashMap<>();
   for(Epic epic : epics){
       if(epicMap.contains(epic.versionName)){
           // Add issue to existing MultiIssueEpic
           epicMap.get(epic.versionName).issueSet.add(epic.issue);
       } else{
           // Add new MultiIssueEpic
           epicMap.put(epic.versionName, new MultiIssueEpic(epic));
       }
   }

   // Here is your list of MultiIssueEpics:
   List<MultiIssueEpic> multiIssueEpics = new ArrayList<>(epicMap.values());
   ```

Comment: @MILIND you should really consider Gson or Jackson.